# Norm-2 and frobenius norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}-3&0&-1\\0&-2&0\\1&0&-3\end{bmatrix}$ calculate $||A||_{(F)}$ and $||A||_{(2)}$.

I know by definitions that $||A||_{(F)}=(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ and $||A||_{(2)}=max(||Ax||_2;||x||_2=1) $
I know too that $||A||_{(2)}=max(|\lambda_i|;i=1,...,n)$ where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of A.What I did is
$$||A||_{(F)}=(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2)^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{(-3)²+(1)²+(2)²+(1)²+(3)²}=\sqrt{34}$$ and for $||A||_{(2)}$ I did $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ and I find the characteristic polynomial $-\lambda³-8\lambda²-20\lambda-16=0$ and find the roots $\lambda_1=-2,\lambda_2=-2,\lambda_3=-4$. So $||A||_{(2)}=max(|\lambda_i|;i=1,...,n)=|-4|=4$\
That is right? Is there any other easier way to find$||A||_{(2)}$ without finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: It's actually $\left \| A\right \|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( A^TA\right )}$. Also, you found eigenvalues wrong.

Comment: Root of the eigenvalues of $A^tA$ @Kaster?

Comment: Square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.